# Taking average over some columns

Tags: r

I have such data

```
        > dput(head(my_data))
structure(list(`Sample Name` = c("ACTB", "ATP5F1", "DDX5", "EEF1G", 
"GAPDH", "NCL"), `31-29TRG1R1_1` = c(4526, 884, 11044, 10661, 
31760, 9417), `31-25TRG2R1_1` = c(5311, 841, 6401, 16073, 20432, 
4969), `31-18TRG1R1_1` = c(12487, 567, 13945, 16474, 43309, 11831
), `31-44TRG2R1_1` = c(9477, 1244, 7140, 6580, 12457, 5176), 
    `31-32TRG2R1_1` = c(13386, 1535, 14153, 11036, 26186, 8299
    ), `31-21TRG3R1_1` = c(8511, 1703, 8966, 14800, 57140, 7002
    ), `31-14TRG4R1_1` = c(9935, 1841, 19590, 16467, 34281, 12463
    ), `31-19TRG4R1_1` = c(5211, 917, 9144, 8024, 8200, 3935), 
    `31-29TRG1R2_1` = c(3181, 613, 7584, 7603, 19331, 6286), 
    `31-25TRG2R2_1` = c(115931, 11738, 88604, 255822, 447002, 
    70197), `31-23TRG1R1_1` = c(3156, 765, 18034, 18982, 17237, 
    18880), `31-RESECTION1_1` = c(3470, 506, 8858, 11829, 29934, 
    7857), `31-32TRG2R2_1` = c(241372, 21547, 165886, 138726, 
    442723, 94629), `31-21TRG3R2_1` = c(5102, 1217, 5977, 10041, 
    35615, 4740), `31-14TRG4R2_1` = c(5352, 1029, 14053, 10995, 
    18206, 8633), `31-24TRG4R1_1` = c(6990, 761, 4440, 2833, 
    8150, 1340), `31-46TRG1R1_1` = c(4290, 834, 8146, 22078, 
    13631, 7407), `31-27TRG2R1_1` = c(11262, 1153, 10063, 13690, 
    19430, 6470), `31-33TRG1R1_1` = c(4139, 338, 8260, 8650, 
    13916, 8000), `31-RESECTION1_2` = c(2812, 497, 8503, 10674, 
    22677, 7394), `31-53TRG2R1_1` = c(7438, 921, 6897, 10042, 
    15142, 8073), `31-22TRG3R1_1` = c(4784, 621, 9904, 7049, 
    13977, 4279), `31-6TRG4R1_1` = c(6749, 704, 9638, 12920, 
    14396, 8133), `31-17TRG3R1_1` = c(10074, 1056, 7966, 12489, 
    26819, 6404), `31-46TRG1R2_1` = c(6586, 1160, 10305, 30012, 
    21850, 9848), `31-27TRG2R2_1` = c(10368, 866, 7324, 10047, 
    17939, 4943), `31-5TRG2R1_1` = c(5479, 440, 8913, 7103, 15886, 
    5801), `31-RESECTION1_3` = c(3032, 474, 8484, 11152, 24847, 
    7741), `31-53TRG2R2_1` = c(10587, 1315, 8675, 12923, 23882, 
    10213), `31-22TRG3R2_1` = c(4885, 660, 9710, 7115, 15669, 
    4908), `31-6TRG4R2_1` = c(6683, 650, 7987, 11447, 14364, 
    7236), `31-16TRG4R1_1` = c(5428, 825, 11789, 12018, 6812, 
    5954), `31-9TRG1R1_1` = c(5723, 494, 7504, 5591, 9086, 2966
    ), `31-26TRG3R1_1` = c(2564, 465, 2115, 2810, 4022, 955), 
    `31-20TRG2R1_1` = c(1018, 491, 2325, 3460, 3469, 1863), `31-RESECTION2_1` = c(1011, 
    285, 2893, 4345, 6476, 1818), `31-52TRG2R1_1` = c(4128, 622, 
    5952, 5196, 7428, 4181), `31-38TRG3R1_1` = c(2281, 521, 12043, 
    8111, 16866, 5207), `31-49TRG4R1_1` = c(4566, 453, 8521, 
    9618, 26104, 8663), `31-15TRG4R1_1` = c(6501, 947, 10320, 
    7285, 10538, 4638), `31-9TRG1R2_1` = c(13212, 1131, 14045, 
    11418, 21843, 6245), `31-26TRG3R2_1` = c(5832, 972, 3012, 
    4851, 7559, 1560), `31-37TRG2R1_1` = c(7031, 690, 8208, 17495, 
    28514, 7058), `31-RESECTION2_2` = c(4095, 620, 6319, 10473, 
    25292, 4274), `31-52TRG2R1_2` = c(10240, 2169, 19618, 17052, 
    18671, 13688), `31-38TRG3R2_1` = c(5009, 874, 20191, 14132, 
    34612, 8855), `31-49TRG4R2_1` = c(10911, 1131, 19318, 21560, 
    58967, 19450), `31-48TRG2R1_1` = c(8758, 1002, 8044, 6677, 
    17354, 7355), `31-2TRG1R1_1` = c(10461, 1904, 15286, 16249, 
    15900, 14393), `31-36TRG3R1_1` = c(16430, 1401, 9522, 17646, 
    26764, 8063), `31-51TRG2R1_1` = c(151880, 16572, 93610, 110556, 
    303604, 57029), `31-RESECTION2_3` = c(9686, 1435, 14038, 
    23464, 61018, 8921), `31-42TRG2R1_1` = c(38649, 3795, 24468, 
    36134, 68794, 17827), `31-3TRG4R1_1` = c(14421, 1901, 34905, 
    21004, 47952, 12428), `31-35TRG4R1_1` = c(59268, 4752, 73216, 
    64854, 212997, 37064), `31-50TRG4R1_1` = c(6660, 701, 4092, 
    16796, 7958, 2408), `31-2TRG1R2_1` = c(4845, 1086, 9191, 
    8887, 6692, 8119), `31-36TRG3R2_1` = c(8418, 868, 6832, 11279, 
    13530, 5233), `31-28TRG4R1_1` = c(7980, 1343, 7342, 9874, 
    14286, 4255), `31-RESECTION3_1` = c(4330, 832, 4446, 6208, 
    13131, 8312), `31-42TRG2R2_1` = c(6745, 1007, 8185, 9790, 
    11478, 5764), `31-3TRG4R2_1` = c(4080, 769, 14648, 8343, 
    14580, 5035), `31-35TRG4R2_1` = c(5290, 684, 11139, 9057, 
    18928, 5325), `31-12TRG4R1_1` = c(7812, 1326, 5750, 9204, 
    12352, 5489), `31-40TRG1R1_1` = c(14399, 922, 13135, 20975, 
    50560, 9952), `31-30TRG5R1_1` = c(24261, 1986, 14361, 26032, 
    89023, 20479), `31-30TRG5R2_1` = c(24454, 2196, 16827, 27964, 
    93862, 21350), `31-34TRG3R1_1` = c(37303, 2998, 22122, 30431, 
    51981, 11737), `31-RESECTION3_2` = c(20019, 1158, 8349, 14393, 
    49299, 17807), `31-7TRG3R1_1` = c(22085, 1431, 12012, 15730, 
    40418, 10271), `31-43TRG3R1_1` = c(11531, 676, 13557, 6762, 
    33468, 5563), `31-11TRG4R1_1` = c(28845, 3840, 28234, 45017, 
    85101, 17277), `31-cells_1` = c(5252, 2077, 6668, 36973, 
    39909, 15035), `31-40TRG1R2_1` = c(43316, 3278, 40684, 65687, 
    157910, 29137), `31-39TRG3R1_1` = c(28273, 2169, 14697, 20890, 
    68353, 25293), `31-RESECTION3_3` = c(27828, 2144, 13246, 
    20487, 69043, 26125), `31-7TRG3R2_1` = c(10299, 879, 6798, 
    8131, 19650, 5182), `31-43TRG3R2_1` = c(16109, 918, 18933, 
    8892, 43115, 6850), `31-11TRG4R2_1` = c(20847, 2748, 22810, 
    32811, 60942, 11978), `31-cells_2` = c(8909, 3453, 10518, 
    49209, 46428, 19275), `31-41TRG1R1_1` = c(12732, 883, 11319, 
    12157, 40460, 10400), `31-8TRG1R1_1` = c(11408, 1007, 11396, 
    20424, 38188, 9570), `31-1TRG3R1_1` = c(9928, 1112, 5726, 
    6227, 12942, 3644), `31-RNA_1` = c(7453, 1324, 4461, 15932, 
    47845, 13711), `31-10TRG3R1_1` = c(13214, 1355, 13559, 14508, 
    31296, 9096), `31-31TRG4R1_1` = c(7230, 769, 11198, 11052, 
    39781, 12827), `31-45TRG3R1_1` = c(12182, 573, 2818, 3699, 
    4365, 1639), `31-cells_3` = c(6517, 1899, 5144, 23862, 30177, 
    8443), `31-41TRG1R2_1` = c(15229, 1485, 15090, 15091, 54369, 
    13341), `31-13TRG1R1_1` = c(15332, 1162, 18268, 20875, 62257, 
    10614), `31-4TRG3R1_1` = c(9947, 1115, 7267, 5957, 13831, 
    2793), `31-RNA_2` = c(10629, 2135, 8014, 27834, 92632, 25041
    ), `31-10TRG3R2_1` = c(18232, 2010, 19637, 19973, 46075, 
    12244), `31-31TRG4R2_1` = c(6362, 1110, 14307, 12233, 44153, 
    13017), `31-47TRG3R1_1` = c(14419, 1927, 7350, 10375, 15736, 
    3415), `31-RNA_3` = c(11938, 1911, 5565, 16496, 49358, 17899
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
>
```

Some columns are duplicated, for instance

`31-30TRG5R1_1` and `31-30TRG5R2_1` are duplications of an individual sample for which I want to take average of these and create a column named `31-30TRG5`

In my data I have many of these cases for these the first part of name is the same with `R1_1` and `R2_1`

Like picture

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Is it possible to have R function to take average of these samples instead of manually locate them and taking average over genes for them?

Comment: How do you *know* that they are duplicates? Is it the leading `31-30TRG5R`?

Comment: Please share data in a way we can use, preferably using `tibble(...)`, `data.frame(...)`, or (most likely) the output from `dput(head(my_data))`.

Comment: only 31-30....R is leading because TRG itself coould be TRG1, TRG2, TRG3, TRG4 and TRG5. I have edited my main post with a repreducible example

Comment: Thank you for updating your question, but it does not reflect the anonymized variables. For this updated sample data with column names `A1`, `A2`, etc, you're saying that the trailing numbers indicate the duplications of the individual sample `A`?

Comment: I know because for a given sample one is R1_1 and another is R2_1

Comment: Oh I see ... your data is corrupt (according to how R thinks of frames). R does not do multiple header rows, so all of your "numbers" are now strings.

Comment: No please ignore WELL part of the data, no point with A1 and A2 , etc. just in Sample Name part of the data, some samples are duplicated having R1_1 and R2_1 while the rest of sample name is the same

Comment: "Ignore" and "fix the fact that your data has been corrupted" are two different things. I'm being pedantic here because the inadvertent conversion of numbers to strings is not always perfectly reversible. It can be if all data are integers, and it usually can be still otherwise, but not always. Any operation the (otherwise needlessly) converts your data from numbers to strings is suspect and really should be avoided if possible. Since it appears that you are reading this from an excel worksheet, a side project should be to correctly read in that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split.default` to split data based on similarity of their column names and take average.

```
result <- cbind(my_data[1], round(sapply(split.default(my_data[-1], 
             sub('\\d_\\d$', '', names(my_data)[-1])), rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Using `sub` we try to keep only the common part of the column names.

```
sub('\\d_\\d$', '', names(my_data)[-1])
# [1] "31-29TRG1R"   "31-25TRG2R"   "31-18TRG1R"   "31-44TRG2R"   "31-32TRG2R"   "31-21TRG3R"  
# [7] "31-14TRG4R"   "31-19TRG4R"   "31-29TRG1R"   "31-25TRG2R"   "31-23TRG1R"   "31-RESECTION"
#[13] "31-32TRG2R"   "31-21TRG3R"   "31-14TRG4R"   "31-24TRG4R"   "31-46TRG1R"   "31-27TRG2R"  
#[19] "31-33TRG1R"   "31-RESECTION" "31-53TRG2R"   "31-22TRG3R"   "31-6TRG4R"    "31-17TRG3R"  
#[25] "31-46TRG1R"   "31-27TRG2R"   "31-5TRG2R"    "31-RESECTION" "31-53TRG2R"   "31-22TRG3R"  
#[31] "31-6TRG4R"    "31-16TRG4R"   "31-9TRG1R"    "31-26TRG3R"   "31-20TRG2R"   "31-RESECTION"
#[37] "31-52TRG2R"   "31-38TRG3R"   "31-49TRG4R"   "31-15TRG4R"   "31-9TRG1R"    "31-26TRG3R"  
#[43] "31-37TRG2R"   "31-RESECTION" "31-52TRG2R"   "31-38TRG3R"   "31-49TRG4R"   "31-48TRG2R"  
#[49] "31-2TRG1R"    "31-36TRG3R"   "31-51TRG2R"   "31-RESECTION" "31-42TRG2R"   "31-3TRG4R"   
#[55] "31-35TRG4R"   "31-50TRG4R"   "31-2TRG1R"    "31-36TRG3R"   "31-28TRG4R"   "31-RESECTION"
#[61] "31-42TRG2R"   "31-3TRG4R"    "31-35TRG4R"   "31-12TRG4R"   "31-40TRG1R"   "31-30TRG5R"  
#[67] "31-30TRG5R"   "31-34TRG3R"   "31-RESECTION" "31-7TRG3R"    "31-43TRG3R"   "31-11TRG4R"  
#[73] "31-cells_1"   "31-40TRG1R"   "31-39TRG3R"   "31-RESECTION" "31-7TRG3R"    "31-43TRG3R"  
[#79] "31-11TRG4R"   "31-cells_2"   "31-41TRG1R"   "31-8TRG1R"    "31-1TRG3R"    "31-RNA_1"    
[#85] "31-10TRG3R"   "31-31TRG4R"   "31-45TRG3R"   "31-cells_3"   "31-41TRG1R"   "31-13TRG1R"  
#[91] "31-4TRG3R"    "31-RNA_2"     "31-10TRG3R"   "31-31TRG4R"   "31-47TRG3R"   "31-RNA_3"
```

Here column number 1 and column number 10 form 1 group and similarly for other such groups.

Comment: How I can make the numbers rounded without any decimal after rowmeans?

Comment: You can use `round`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to first "fix" the corrupted data, since you can't have two rows of column headers. The *best* fix is to begin with properly imported data, perhaps skipping one of the header rows when you read it in. Lacking that, ...

This makes the assumption that `` `Sample Name` `` is the only properly "string" data, and all others are strictly numeric.

```r
library(dplyr)
colnames(my_data) <- my_data[1,]
my_data <- my_data[-1,]
my_data <- mutate_at(my_data, vars(-`Sample Name`), as.numeric)
```

From here, I'll pivot the data into a "longer" format, group by the stem of the sample name, summarize, and then un-pivot back into the "wider" format. (If you're going to stay with "tidy" principles, including the use of `ggplot2`, it is almost certainly better to keep your data in the "longer" format. Over to you!)

```r
my_data2 <- my_data %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(., -`Sample Name`, names_to = "sample", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(sample0 = gsub("[_0-9]+$", "", sample)) %>%
  group_by(`Sample Name`, sample0) %>%
  summarize(
    sample = sample[1], # arbitrarily choosing the first sample name
    value = mean(value)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-sample0) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "sample", values_from = "value")
my_data2
# # A tibble: 5 x 57
#   `Sample Name` `31-10TRG3R1_1` `31-11TRG4R1_1` `31-12TRG4R1_1` `31-13TRG1R1_1` `31-14TRG4R1_1`
#   <chr>                   <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1 ACTB                   15723           24846             7812           15332           7644.
# 2 ATP5F1                  1682.           3294             1326            1162           1435 
# 3 DDX5                   16598           25522             5750           18268          16822.
# 4 EEF1G                  17240.          38914             9204           20875          13731 
# 5 GAPDH                  38686.          73022.           12352           62257          26244.
# # ... with 51 more variables: `31-15TRG4R1_1` <dbl>, `31-16TRG4R1_1` <dbl>,
# #   `31-17TRG3R1_1` <dbl>, `31-18TRG1R1_1` <dbl>, `31-19TRG4R1_1` <dbl>, `31-1TRG3R1_1` <dbl>,
# #   `31-20TRG2R1_1` <dbl>, `31-21TRG3R1_1` <dbl>, `31-22TRG3R1_1` <dbl>, `31-23TRG1R1_1` <dbl>,
# #   `31-24TRG4R1_1` <dbl>, `31-25TRG2R1_1` <dbl>, `31-26TRG3R1_1` <dbl>, `31-27TRG2R1_1` <dbl>,
# #   `31-28TRG4R1_1` <dbl>, `31-29TRG1R1_1` <dbl>, `31-2TRG1R1_1` <dbl>, `31-30TRG5R1_1` <dbl>,
# #   `31-31TRG4R1_1` <dbl>, `31-32TRG2R1_1` <dbl>, `31-33TRG1R1_1` <dbl>, `31-34TRG3R1_1` <dbl>,
# #   `31-35TRG4R1_1` <dbl>, `31-36TRG3R1_1` <dbl>, `31-37TRG2R1_1` <dbl>, `31-38TRG3R1_1` <dbl>,
# #   `31-39TRG3R1_1` <dbl>, `31-3TRG4R1_1` <dbl>, `31-40TRG1R1_1` <dbl>, `31-41TRG1R1_1` <dbl>,
# #   `31-42TRG2R1_1` <dbl>, `31-43TRG3R1_1` <dbl>, `31-44TRG2R1_1` <dbl>, `31-45TRG3R1_1` <dbl>,
# #   `31-46TRG1R1_1` <dbl>, `31-47TRG3R1_1` <dbl>, `31-48TRG2R1_1` <dbl>, `31-49TRG4R1_1` <dbl>,
# #   `31-4TRG3R1_1` <dbl>, `31-50TRG4R1_1` <dbl>, `31-51TRG2R1_1` <dbl>, `31-52TRG2R1_1` <dbl>,
# #   `31-53TRG2R1_1` <dbl>, `31-5TRG2R1_1` <dbl>, `31-6TRG4R1_1` <dbl>, `31-7TRG3R1_1` <dbl>,
# #   `31-8TRG1R1_1` <dbl>, `31-9TRG1R1_1` <dbl>, `31-cells_1` <dbl>, `31-RESECTION1_1` <dbl>,
# #   `31-RNA_1` <dbl>
```

As a demonstration of what was removed, we'll diff the column names, where these listed here have been removed (averaged into the original sample name):

```r
setdiff(names(my_data), names(my_data2))
#  [1] "31-29TRG1R2_1"   "31-25TRG2R2_1"   "31-32TRG2R2_1"   "31-21TRG3R2_1"   "31-14TRG4R2_1"  
#  [6] "31-RESECTION1_2" "31-46TRG1R2_1"   "31-27TRG2R2_1"   "31-RESECTION1_3" "31-53TRG2R2_1"  
# [11] "31-22TRG3R2_1"   "31-6TRG4R2_1"    "31-RESECTION2_1" "31-9TRG1R2_1"    "31-26TRG3R2_1"  
# [16] "31-RESECTION2_2" "31-52TRG2R1_2"   "31-38TRG3R2_1"   "31-49TRG4R2_1"   "31-RESECTION2_3"
# [21] "31-2TRG1R2_1"    "31-36TRG3R2_1"   "31-RESECTION3_1" "31-42TRG2R2_1"   "31-3TRG4R2_1"   
# [26] "31-35TRG4R2_1"   "31-30TRG5R2_1"   "31-RESECTION3_2" "31-40TRG1R2_1"   "31-RESECTION3_3"
# [31] "31-7TRG3R2_1"    "31-43TRG3R2_1"   "31-11TRG4R2_1"   "31-cells_2"      "31-cells_3"     
# [36] "31-41TRG1R2_1"   "31-RNA_2"        "31-10TRG3R2_1"   "31-31TRG4R2_1"   "31-RNA_3"
```